# clip-path width doesn't 100% width

Tags: html, css, svg, clip-path

[image]

Hello, I'm using slick slider and I want to clip-path  the container but the clip-path doesn't work well..

this is my svg path

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="mask1">
            <path id="curve" d="m242.6,393.7c-82.2,-4.7 -138.1,-15.4 -191.2,-36.6 -19.3,-7.7 -36.4,-16.1 -47.7,-23.5l-3.2,-2.1 -0,-71.5c-0,-39.3 -0.1,-113.9 -0.3,-165.8l-0.3,-94.2 371.1,0 371.1,0 0,152 0,152 -5.8,3.7c-7.8,5 -14.5,8.8 -23.4,13.4 -70.4,36.3 -187.2,62.5 -317.4,71.2 -28.6,1.9 -31.6,2 -91.2,1.9 -31,-0 -58.8,-0.2 -61.9,-0.4z">
            </path>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

the slider works but the clip-path doesn't fit the 100% window..

Thanks.. and sorry for my English..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should convert your `clipPath` to one using bounding box units:

```
<clipPath clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox" ... >
```

When you use bounding box units, all your clip path coordinates should be defined in the range 0..1.

http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/masking.html#EstablishingANewClippingPath

If you do this, the clipping path will be given the same size as the the element you apply it to.

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  clip-path: url(#mask1);
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#mask1);
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="mask1" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
            <path id="curve"
                  transform="scale(0.00135, 0.00254)"
                  d="m242.6,393.7c-82.2,-4.7 -138.1,-15.4 -191.2,-36.6 -19.3,-7.7 -36.4,-16.1 -47.7,-23.5l-3.2,-2.1 -0,-71.5c-0,-39.3 -0.1,-113.9 -0.3,-165.8l-0.3,-94.2 371.1,0 371.1,0 0,152 0,152 -5.8,3.7c-7.8,5 -14.5,8.8 -23.4,13.4 -70.4,36.3 -187.2,62.5 -317.4,71.2 -28.6,1.9 -31.6,2 -91.2,1.9 -31,-0 -58.8,-0.2 -61.9,-0.4z">
            </path>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>


<img src="//placekitten.com/400/150"/>
```

What I have done in the example above is to use a `transform` to scale the clip path to size 1x1.  It's easier than recreating the shape with new coordinates.

Comment: But can I asking why there is an another mask below it? like mask2?

Comment: I was testing something and forgot to remove it. I have fixed the example now.

Comment: You call `getBBox()` on the path. That will return the width and height of the path. You can then calculate the scales by dividing them into 1 (ie 1 / width etc).  If your path is not at (0,0) then you may also have to include a `translate()` in your transform.

Comment: You can use JS.  The values I used I got by calling `getBBox()` on the path  on a test page. Then I manually calculated the scale factors. :)

Comment: Great Answer. This article covers the transform in more detail:
http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2017/02/24/scaling-svg-clipping-paths-for-css-use/

Comment: That article is a bit different. It assumes the `viewBox` matches the path. But that is often not the case.